# Reveal hidden span element Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code:

```
<body><span hidden>E</span><span>U</span><span>$</span><span>U</span><span>W</span><span>X</span><span>F</span><span>1</span><span>6</span><span>X</span><span>a</span><span>Y</span><span>)</span><span>a</span><span>l</span><span>1</span><span>D</span><span>(</span><span>M</span><span>J</span><span>K</span><span>%</span><span>y</span><span>X</span><span>x</span><span>f</span><span>y</span><span>W</span><span>:</span><span>}</span><span>N</span><span>k</span><span>z</span><span>E</span><span>o</span><span>k</span><span>2</span><span>N</span><span>)</span><span>R</span><span>$</span><span>d</span><span>Z</span><span>F</span><span>j</span><span hidden>l</span><span>J</span><span>A</span><span>#</span><span>6</span><span>9</span><span>n</span><span>(</span><span>!</span><span>I</span><span>u</span><span>:</span><span>b</span><span>R</span><span>n</span><span>k</span><span>$</span><span>*</span><span>c</span><span>8</span><span>s</span><span>?</span><span>?</span><span>8</span><span>:</span><span>$</span><span>I</span><span>I</span><span>1</span><span>B</span><span>3</span><span>f</span><span>O</span><span>V</span><span>(</span><span>n</span><span>y</span><span>3</span><span>f</span><span>d</span><span>i</span><span>D</span><span>Y</span><span>2</span><span>S</span><span hidden>e</span><span>k</span><span>W</span><span>g</span><span>z</span><span>C</span><span>c</span><span>o</span><span>r</span><span>$</span><span>X</span><span>o</span><span>T</span><br /><span>B</span><span>#</span><span>c</span><span>N</span><span>O</span><span>%</span><span>n</span><span>Q</span><span>J</span><span>9</span><span>Q</span><span>E</span><span>Y</span><span>4</span><span>B</span><span>5</span><span>L</span><span>E</span><span>o</span><span>B</span><span>S</span><span>r</span><span>p</span><span>@</span><span>&</span><span>e</span><span>M</span><span>G</span><span>O</span><span>j</span><span>&</span><span>h</span><span>L</span><span>O</span><span>i</span><span>N</span><span>f</span><span>%</span><span>O</span><span>x</span><span>y</span><span>O</span><span>H</span><span>m</span><span>X</span><span>C</span><span>3</span><span>V</span><span>^</span><span>z</span><span>7</span><span>5</span><span>{</span><span>$</span><span>e</span><span>y</span><span>Y</span><span>n</span><span hidden>g</span><span>H</span><span>@</span><span>M</span><span>A</span><span>t</span><span>l</span><span>o</span><span>m</span><span>n</span><span>n</span><span>B</span><span hidden>a</span>
```

I would like to reveal all `span` element that are hidden and hide all the other  `span` element that do not have a hidden attribute. How could I achieve it using JavaScript/jQuery?

**update**
Thanks to the question answered I can reveal the hidden elements with `$('span').toggle();`
Here is the new output:

```
El
egan
tly
un
sc
ram
ble
t
his 
me
ss
ag
e us
ing
t
he
s
pac
e p
rov
i
ded
. 
Th
en
wr
it
e 
th
e 
s
cram
b
le
r 
tha
t m
ade
it.
Th
e 
ans
we
r
is
a
n o
bj
ec
t
w
it
h 
glob
al
sc
op
e
t
h
at c
an
scra
m
ble 
and
un
sc
r
amb
le 
any
t
ex
t a
ny
num
ber

of 
ti
mes
.
```

I'd like this to be nicely formatted into a `<p>` tag for example. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Please read the JQuery API's: https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really easy with jQuery:

```
$('span').toggle();
```

And to remove the line breaks:

```
$('br').remove();
```

Comment: I'm not sure but this works. except i'd like it to be nicely formatted like in a `<p></p>` tag. look at the update above

Comment: There are `<br>` tags in your input which is what is causing some `span`s to go on a new line.

Comment: Then all you have to do is use `$('br').hide();` or `$('br').show();`

Comment: Yeah sorry just figured that out. I Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you are looking for:

```
$('span').wrapAll('<p>');
```

More info at: http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/

Comment: Wouldn't it be `$('span').wrapAll('<p>');`